# ListViews Behind ActionBar

Tags: android

I made one Activity with a NavigationView. When I select one item of NavigationView it loads one fragment.
This is the .xml that contains the layouts for my activity and fragment:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:fitsSystemWindows="true">

<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        //Layout for activity
        <RelativeLayout
            android:id="@+id/Separator"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            >

            <ListView
                android:id="@+id/FirstList"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:choiceMode="multipleChoice"
                android:clickable="false" />


        </RelativeLayout>

        //Layout for fragment
        <RelativeLayout
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content">

            <ListView
                android:id="@+id/SecondList"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent" />
        </RelativeLayout>
    </LinearLayout>

    <include
        layout="@layout/app_bar_main"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

</RelativeLayout>

<android.support.design.widget.NavigationView
    android:id="@+id/nav_view"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_gravity="start"
    app:headerLayout="@layout/nav_header_main"
    app:menu="@menu/activity_main_drawer" />

 </android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

The problem is the lists (ListViews). They are behind the action bar and I don't know why. 
[image]

I think the problem is with the .xml. But if it necessary I provide more code. Thanks.

Edit app_bar.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
>

<android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme.AppBarOverlay">

    <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
        android:id="@+id/toolbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
        android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
        app:popupTheme="@style/AppTheme.PopupOverlay" />

</android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>



</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

Comment: are you using same xml for activity and fragment if not please separate in your question

Comment: Yes, I am using the same .xml.

Comment: can i see your `app_bar_main.xml` ??

Comment: see my answer @tomss

Answer (score 0):

This is happening because of the wrong xml.

```
<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

   <LinearLayout
```

> Add a id for this layout.

```
        android:id="@+id/list_layout"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical">
```

> Add then finally make the following change in app_bar_main

```
<include
    layout="@layout/app_bar_main"
    android:layout_above="@id/list_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
```

Comment: I have made the changes in your answer. Now the ActionBar has dissapeared. I think is out of the screen.